# How to disconnect from the BLE device in UWP

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I m connecting to the BLE device using windows 10 on PC. I am using Gatt Client to connect to the device to read and write data. The disconnection from the device does not work.

```
public static async Task Disconnect(BluetoothLEDevice device)
    {

        GattDeviceServicesResult result = await device.GetGattServicesAsync();
        var services = result.Services;

        foreach (var service in services)
        {
            GattCharacteristicsResult results = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
            foreach (var charac in results.Characteristics)
            {
                charac.Service?.Session.Dispose();


            }


            service?.Dispose();

        }


        device.Dispose();
        await Task.Delay(80000);
        var status = device.ConnectionStatus; // **This still shows connected**

        device = null;

        GC.Collect();
```

Comment: Service.Close()

Comment: It does not contain the definition of Close() thus I am using Service.Dispose();

Comment: You disposed device and then trying to read its property. That;s wrong way. The device object is disposed and after that you should not use it. After disposing you should create new object and check its status.

Comment: I tried it and i can still see the device is connected to the BLE. How long does it takes before it disconnects? Will this BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(address).Close(); work?

Comment: Interesting thing. Actually it should be closed once you released all services. May be characteristic also has to be released. Try to call Dispose for chars also. And before Device.Dispose() call Device.Close().

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.But you can try to dispose characteristic: charac?.Service?.Dispose() or use the [BluetoothLE sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE) to check if the issue still exists.

Comment: foreach (var charac in results.Characteristics)
            {
                charac.Service?.Session.Dispose();


            }
Hi, this code above disposes all the characteristics. I am still not sure why its holding onto the device.

Comment: Can you tell us the build of your Windows?

Comment: Its version 1803 (OS Build 17134.885)

Comment: Could you please try to check the session status by calling Service?.Session.SessionStatus or charac.Service?.Session.SessionStatus to make sure that all the sessions have been closed. Besides, according to this doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client#connecting-to-the-device), please make sure that there is no other app on the system has a reference to the device.